# How do I convert text to datetime in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, text

I want to convert text to datetime in SQL Server.

I have text which in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`, but I want to convert this text format to datetime `yyyymmdd`.

I am using this method.

```
Convert(varchar(8), Right(text, 4) + Substring(text, 4, 2) + Left(text, 2), 112)
```

BUT I need a simpler query.

Comment: You are converting text to text. so you don't need to use CONVERT function. just user the left, right and substring

Comment: Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(date, '30/01/2018', 103), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

**Explanation:**

So this one is a little trickier because you've got DD/MM/YYYY, so you need to CONVERT first:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, '30/01/2018', 103)
```

Result: `2018-01-30`

Then if you are using SQL Server 2012+ use [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql)

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(date, '30/01/2018', 103), 'yyyyMMdd')
```

Result: `20180130`